# IRDP protocol nowadays

Tags: routing, dhcp

I'm considering to remove [`rdisc`](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/blob/master/rdisc.c) tool from iputils project (see https://github.com/iputils/iputils/issues/363). This tool implements [ICMP Internet Router Discovery Protocol (IRDP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMP_Router_Discovery_Protocol).

Is IRDP really useful nowadays as [suggested](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/issues/363#issuecomment-889784624) in the ticket that it justify time investment for maintaining it? Yes, source is small, but still, if everybody uses DHCP, why to keep the software? (it stays in git history).

NOTE: feel free to respond directly to the issue https://github.com/iputils/iputils/issues/363.

Comment: Nothing has actively used (supported?) ICMP router discovery for many decades. I'm insulted IPv6 resurrected that BS.

Comment: Thx for info. BTW what's *BS*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR** it's fine to drop it.

Well, first in almost 20 years of managing various customer networks I have never seen irdp used.

Secondly I examined the argument given by 6eh01der which are:

> DHCP is more complex to configure and it will not save your machines
> from gateway death and also for DHCP server failover scenarios you
> should implement some reserve instance and some kind of replication
> between them in some scenarios. I don't think that all dns server
> implementations support automatic failover... About gateway - yes, you
> could announce some VIP for clients,(for example if you have two
> gateways with keepalived), but not allways you could have a keepalived
> or something similar,(i know only one another VRRP implementation -
> vrrpd, for Windows there is no VRRP at all, but with Routing and
> Remote Access it can act as IRDP server). And so in some situations it
> may be appropriate to have some routers with IRDP server and rdisc as
> client at other machines. Gateway will be choosed by annoucement
> preference, so if announcement with higher preference is no more seen
> another with lower will be applied. Work and simple gateway failover.
> Also i see that IRDP present in Juniper, Cisco and Ruckus
> documentation and it looks like their devices still support it.
> [source](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/issues/363#issuecomment-889784624)

but I don"t find them relevant to modern enterprise networking.

> DHCP is more complex to configure

Well I don't think many people will agree. Maybe irdp is even simpler than DHCP, but DHCP is well known, simple enough, and cover many other needs, some of them essentials (DNS settings...) for which IRDP is not suitable.

> it will not save your machines from gateway death [...] yes, you
> could announce some VIP for clients,(for example if you have two
> gateways with keepalived), but not allways you could have a keepalived
> or something similar

Yes, we do use VRRP for this, which is supported by any serious network device, or increasingly various (albeit proprietary)  Multi Active Gateway Protocols. Otherwise, I don't see the point about keepalive.

> for Windows there is no VRRP at all but with Routing and
> Remote Access it can act as IRDP server

Using Windows as a router? This is pure masochism.

> Also i see that IRDP present in Juniper, Cisco and Ruckus
> documentation and it looks like their devices still support it.

Pure inertia. The same reason while we still have ifconfig despite it being deprecated for more than 20 years. There's many other never-used features still supported.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen a router answer one, and immediately thought MITM attack when I saw them years ago.  Please remove it, trust me - I've seen a lot of packets.